# Перебрать массив, с целью сгрупировать в тройки все возможные в этом массиве комбинации из членов массива

Tags: javascript

Не могу сложить в голове, как возможно такое сотворить )
Задача в заголовке : Из некоего массива arr = [1,2,4,9,5] нужно сформировать все возможные комбинации из 3 членов этого массива т.е. [1,5,9], [2,4,9], [5,1,2] ... etc

Comment: В комбинаторике это задача размещения из n по k без повторений

Comment: А все пары значений вывесит умеете?

Comment: Если речь идёт именно о тройках, и не понадобятся комбинации большего размера, то проще всего использовать три вложенных цикла

Comment: "задача размещения из n по k без повторений – Laukhin Andrey": Прочитал. Хорошая теория ) ! Только Я осознал, что понимал суть этой фразы в общем смысле. И путаница в голове до сих пор ...

Comment: "А все пары значений вывесит умеете? – Stanislav Volodarskiy" не понимаю Вас. Циклом + console.log() , alert() ...

Comment: "Если речь идёт именно о тройках, и не понадобятся комбинации большего размера, то проще всего использовать три вложенных цикла – 
MBo" : Да, Я в ступоре. Первичная постановка задачи выявила незнание мной базовых понятий. В теории, у меня должны быть 60 комбинаций. Я проанализировал. Оказалось, мне нужны СОЧЕТАНИЯ )))

Comment: @andriishch "Оказалось, мне нужны СОЧЕТАНИЯ" - Вы уверены? При размещении важен порядок элементов, т. е. наборы [1, 2, 3] и [3, 2, 1]  считаются различными. При сочетании порядок элементов не важен. Т. е. такие наборы считаются одинаковыми